# AngleSharp - Processing self closed tags

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, anglesharp

When parsing an html fragment containing self closed tags:

```
var text = @"<tag /> and another <tag />";
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var originalHtml = parser.Parse(text);
```

The resulting output of OuterHtml is:

```
<tag> and another <tag></tag></tag>
```

I know that anglesharp does not "renders" self closing tags without a custom formatter, but is this output expected, considering the input ?

I would expect something like:

```
<tag></tag> and another <tag></tag>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with AngleSharp, but rather with the HTML5 specification. Self-closing is only permitted on a few elements (and mostly just for backwards compatibility - actually in proper HTML5 you would never self-close, but rather use the implicit self-closing, i.e., prefer `<img>` over `<img />` and `<meta>` over `<meta />`).

That all being written: Since the tag you've provided (`tag`) is not known, it is therefore not an exception (the list of exceptions is short - the two ones mentioned above are in this list). If you want to use a similar tag to your custom one, use `div`.

Now compare the output of using

```
var text = @"<div /> and another <div />";
```

to

```
var text = @"<img /> and another <img />";
```

You should see that the latter (using `img`) gets you the expected output (serialized differently, but the generated DOM will be equivalent), while `div` will look like the current output.

Important to remember: HTML may seem like a subset of XML, but in fact it is not. It is also not a superset. HTML started deviating some time ago and HTML5 was only brought into life to finally bring sanity on the parser side by providing a common way to deal with any kind of unexpected markup.

Hope this helps!